# AngularJS remove "active" class if progress bar is 100%

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, progress-bar

i want to remove the bootstrap 'active' class from the progress bar when it reaches 100%, so the stripes stop moving.

this is not working:

```
<div class="progress progress-striped active" style="margin-bottom: 0;"
     ng-class="{'active': false}>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a condition in `ng-class`

Working fiddle is:: http://jsfiddle.net/5DMjt/2221/

Let me know if you need anymore help.

Comment: hi there, thanks for the answer but this is not what i need. i dont need to deactivate the class with the click of a button but i want the animated stripes to stop animating after the progress reaches 100%. this is the progress bar im using: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_progressbar5&stacked=h

Comment: So you can do like::

ng-class="{ 'active' : isActive() }>

IN JS:: $scope.isActive = function() {
// return true if progress 100%
}